# Sly Lisp program only shows first prompt

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I'm following along with the book Practical Common Lisp and I'm getting unexpected behavior. The code is the following:

```lisp
(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *standard-output* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *standard-output*)
  (read-line *standard-input*))

(defun prompt-for-cd ()
  (make-cd
   (prompt-read "Title")
   (prompt-read "Artist")
   (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
   (y-or-n-p "Ripped [y/n]: ")))
```

The program is supposed to prompt a user for a title, accept a title, prompt a user for an artist, accept an artist, etc. until the user has entered all the information. Just running prompt-read in the REPL successfully prompts the user for the desired prompt and returns the result. However, this is my output from running prompt-for-cd:
[image]

My program still accepts input, but it stops prompting the user after the first prompt.

Compiling and loading the file where I define the functions seems to show the prompts that should have been shown to the user the last time I ran prompt-for-cd. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like:
[image]

After some investigation, I noticed that this is only happening in Sly's REPL. Here's the output of the program when I just load the file with SBCL:
[image]

How can I get console prompts to work as expected in Sly?

Comment: https://github.com/joaotavora/sly/issues/426 and https://github.com/joaotavora/sly/issues/347 looks like exactly your problem (MacOSX?)

Comment: the simplest answer here is starting your slynk server separately and connecting with "sly-connect" instead of starting sbcl when running "sly", and/or disabling the use of a dedicated stream : `(setf slynk:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)`: https://github.com/joaotavora/sly/issues/196

Comment: I can't edit the tag due to too many pending edits, but the [tag:sly] tag is for the Lex/Yacc Python replacement.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I edited the tags but its a shame that tagging works like this